# Override ActiveResource attribute setter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to override an attribute setter on activeresource when the object is initialized ?

Comment: what exactly you want to do/change?

Comment: I want to cleanify one of the attributes like i would do with ActiveRecord write_attribute method. I can't find an equivalent with ARes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to override load method

```
 def load(attributes, remove_root = false)
       super(attributes, remove_root)
       #put your code,  here you have @attributes collection
       self
    end
```